# Python Requests module - Import Error: No module named requests

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I'm trying to use the requests module, but I'm having trouble importing it. I'm running Python 3.4.2 (which I checked is officially supported) on Windows 7.

I've tried installing it the following ways, each time with no luck:

- Using `pip install requests`.
- Downloading the zipball and installing using `setup.py install`
- Downloading the source code and manually copying the folder to `Python34/Lib/site-packages`.

In all those cases, I can see that the requests library is in the site-packages folder.

If I run import requests from the python interpreter, it works fine. This works:

```
$ python
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get("http://127.0.0.1")
<Response [200]>
```

But this does not work:

```
import requests

r = get('http://127.0.0.1':5000')
```

It always results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I'm completely out of ideas and not sure what else to try!

**EDIT**
Turns out I was running more than one version of Python. I also had 2.7.7 installed. As was suggested, running `import sys; print sys.path` returned Python 2.7.7. Uninstalling that old version fixed the problem.

Comment: Do you have >1 installation of Python?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was wondering. In the Python 3 shell, the Python 3 compiler is directly referenced. During normal execution, the Python 2 compiler will be use unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Print the version of python in both the interpreter and your script and see if they match. They probably don't (import sys; print(sys.version))

Comment: can you copy your `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` output?

Comment: that code should give syntax error first

Comment: You're all totally right! `import(sys; print(sys.version))` returns `Python 2.7.7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run with Python 3 from the command line:

```
python3 script.py
```